Una domanda da due mesi fa con i commenti e le risposte da quattro anni fa?

See the image above, the question was asked in July 2, but there are several answers and comments from 2013.
How did that happen?

Welcome to Italian.SE!

This happens because there were two questions, one from December 2013 and another one posted recently, which were asking about the same topic and which had some answers, so we decided to merge them in such a way that we could find all answers in the same place. Since the asker of the older question deleted the account some years ago, we decided to leave the recent question as the master one and mark the older one as duplicate.   
